# How to return from the first file to second file with one operation

Tags: python

- I have 2 python file, 1.py and 2.py
- 1.py is main python file which going to execute

2.py have below data

```
list_ = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'ABC', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'role': 'Tester'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'CDE', 'email': 'cde@gmail.com', 'role': 'Developer'}]
def return_list():
   l = []
   for i lin list_:
        return (l.append(i['id']))
```

My 1.py have below data

```
import 1.py
def test():
    list_ids = 1.return_list()
    return list_ids
```

- In the 2.py file I am writing return_list() function for other operations which i m not posting here since code snippet will become big. Like with that return ids I am going to crawl the website like that
- In the 1.py also file I am writing return_list() function for other operations
- since in 2.py file return_list() first operations is done
- Since in 1.py also have return_list() also second operation is done

My Ask

Is there any way that return_list() should do only one operation,

Solution I have is merge both file to one. Is there any solution is there apart from this

Comment: As noted below, if you plan to import a Python file, its name must follow the same convention as Python identifiers and **not** begin with a digit.

Comment: What do you mean by "`return_list()` should do only one operation"?

Comment: Your 2.py `return_list` function will return only `None` due to `return (l.append(i['id']))`.

Answer (score -1):

it is recommended to not use numbers as the name of a file. instead rename them as one.py and two.py

```
import two
return_val = two.return_list()
```

Comment: Your answer does not answer the original question.